# i need help to plot this data with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

well , i don't know much about javascript
i have some data that i want to plot using Highcharts , right now i'm following this tuto : 
http://blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/
i managed to do that example , but i have different data like this :

```
    date        : temp
```

2013-05-08 20:17:26  :  -22

2013-05-08 20:18:26  :  -21

2013-05-08 20:24:26  :  -22

2013-05-08 20:37:26  :  -20

2013-05-08 20:40:26  :  -22

2013-05-08 20:47:26  :  -21

2013-05-08 20:52:26  :  -20

2013-05-08 20:53:26  :  -19

how to plot this with date in x axis and temp in y axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot dates/times on the xaxis, use the [xaxis type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) to specify [datetime](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime/).

```
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      }
```

Next you'll need to format your xvalues in the time format Highcharts understands; the number of milliseconds from midnight of January 1, 1970.  You have two options:

1. Parse the date string as in your example link:

   ```
   line = line.split(/\t/);
   date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC'); // change timezone accordingly
   ```
2. Have PHP/MySQL return milliseconds instead of a string from the database:

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timespan) * 1000, visits FROM highcharts_php");
   ```

Comment: Hey , thank you for your reply Mark , it's working very good :)
i have an other question if you don't mind :
i already have 'temperature' in the Y-axis and 'Date' in the x-axis , how can i add more data and retrieve them in tool-tip ?

Comment: You can use formatter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and extract data by point.options.nameofcustomparameter